# Uploading a file to AWS S3 from Android Wear

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wear-os

I am trying to upload a file from Android Wear (currently using an emulator with API 26) to AWS S3.

My code snippet is

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
            REGION
    );

AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(AppController.getCredentialProvider()); //Instantiate an S3 client.
s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));

TransferUtility transfer_utility = new TransferUtility(s3, this); 

TransferObserver observer = transfer_utility.upload(
            BUCKET_NAME,    
            file.getName(),
            file             
    );
```

observer returns "bytesTotal = 5", but bytesTransferred is 0 and the file doesn't appear in my S3 bucket. I tried AWS S3TransferUtilitySample working on an Android Phone and it was successfully uploaded on the bucket. So I doubt that it is an issue of the Cognito, S3 or IAM settings.
Is there an issue with my code or Android Wear 2.0 doesn't support to transfer data to AWS S3 yet?

Comment: The aws android sdk does not support android wear officially. It is not tested and might not work. you could try doing a put object api call instead of transfer utility

Comment: @DianeMadera did you manage to find a solution to this problem?